# PHP Jquery Ajax - Get Url Param

Tags: php, jquery, get

I am working on an Ajax Login form. On the PHP processing page when the login is successful, there are 3 options to redirect the user.

```
<?php
// ------------------------------------------------------------
// PROCESS LOGIN FORM ON POSTBACK
// ------------------------------------------------------------

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    ...

    // 1. DEFAULT URL: default destination url from config
    $plLoginDestinationUrl = PL_DEFAULT_LOGIN_DESTINATION;

    // 2. RETURN URL: if return address present in url
    if (isset($_GET['ReturnUrl'])) {
        $plLoginDestinationUrl = $_GET['ReturnUrl'];
    }

    // 3. PER USER URL: if custom user destination in db exists
    if ($pllogin->loginDestinationUrl != 'default') {
        $plLoginDestinationUrl = $pllogin->loginDestinationUrl;
    }
}
```

If the form is submitted without javascript (jquery), everything works fine. Submitting the page with ajax fails on #2. It just won't parse the $_GET['ReturnUrl'].

The PHP error response I always get when submitting with ajax is: Notice: Undefined index: ReturnUrl in.

Comment: Can you post the JavaScript AJAX?

Answer (score 0):

Ajax is most likely POSTing not GETing.
Try and replace `$_GET['ReturnUrl'];` to `$_POST['ReturnUrl'];` or even `$_REQUEST['ReturnUrl'];`

Comment: Yes, ajax is used with post method but this part of the code is PHP processing only. Shouldn't php just do what its told?

Comment: I just want PHP to grab the value of the url parameter, put it in a variable and echo back the json_encode result to ajax.

Comment: did you try $_REQUEST['ReturnUrl'];